# perl Sys::Statistics::Linux equivalent in FreeBSD?

Tags: perl, freebsd

Dear community members,

Under linux I had a script ([lcd_sysmon](http://pastebin.com/MXEW6DF4)) which was showing system info on the lcd 20x4 display(via LCDd). Now I'm trying to use it on FreeBSD but it gives me an error:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Sys::Statistics::Linux"
>   (perhaps you forgot to load "Sys::Statistics::Linux"?) at lcd_sysmon
>   line 73.

Can someone point me to the proper solution. Is there an equivalent for Sys::Statistics::Linux on the FreeBSD?

Thanks in advance.
pepesz

Comment: Try [searching on metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/search?q=bsd).

Comment: Are you asking if there's a drop-in replacement? I'm sure you already looked, so the answer is obviously no. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Schwern: Thanks for the tip, I will try to get something from there.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm asking because there might be something (slightly different name or name convention) which I missed. Otherwise I'm asking how to adjust the script to have it working on the freebsd system.

Answer (score 1):

[Sys::Statistics::Linux](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Statistics::Linux#TECHNICAL-NOTE) uses [procfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs&sektion=&n=1), but FreeBSD unlike Linux doesn't offers procfs on default. So to use the aforementioned script you have to [mount](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/procfs.html) procfs manually and - because there is no FreeBSD [port](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=Sys%3A%3AStatistics%3A%3ALinux&stype=all) - to install [Sys::Statistics::Linux](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Statistics::Linux#TECHNICAL-NOTE) manually.

> If an application requires procfs, add the following entry to
>   `/etc/fstab`:
>
> `proc                /proc           procfs  rw,noauto       0       0`
>
> Including noauto will prevent /proc from being automatically mounted
>   at boot.
>
> To mount the file system without rebooting:
>
> `# mount /proc`

Comment: I mount /proc and then tried to make the Sys::Statistics::Linux. Running `make test` outputs bunch of `skipped: it seems that your system doesn't provide cpu (etc.) statistics` and then it stops with error: `Error code 255`. Full output: [link](http://pastebin.com/a3XDGGJG).

Comment: You have a permissions issue, if procfs is mounted properly. Is `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` present and is readable on you system?

Comment: I'm bit confused. This is the content of the /proc: 
`0/ 10/ 11/ 13/ 15/ 17/ 19/ 194/ 20/ 21/ 23/ 24/ 255/ 29489/ 3810/ 44696/ 5/ 57605/ 59477/ 59624/ 6/ 60211/ 60321/ 60494/ 60717/ 60976/ 61556/ 62756/ 68854/ 8/ 9/ 9112/ 1/ 10808/ 12/ 14/ 16/ 18/ 19358/ 2/ 207/ 22/ 238/ 24266/ 28788/ 3/ 4/ 45350/ 5340/ 59364/ 59497/ 59855/ 60061/ 60276/ 60492/ 60611/ 60925/ 61306/ 6219/ 66907/ 7/ 8424/ 9048/ curproc@`

Comment: This in on the opnsense 17.1 system which is build on freebsd 11. Not sure if this might be the reason - probably not. I'm linux user and playing with bsd for just last two days, so it is not easy for me to know what should I expect, which makes it more tricky. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you have only limited set of information in `proc` on FreeBSD. `man procfs`: "The process file system, or procfs, implements a view of the system process table inside the file system." So there is no `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`. If you want to use the script after all you should gather required information with [sysctl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysctl(8)) and put it on right place. Example for hostname: `sysctl  kern.hostname`. Or you switch to something BSD convenient like [BSD::Sysctl](https://metacpan.org/pod/BSD::Sysctl)